# Select statement for trial balance display from table with only one amount column and debit credit column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, reporting

**I am trying to populate data table using SQL query from MySQL/MariaDB, to display it as *Trial Balance* for a report.**

My DB engine is **MariaDB 10.4.19**

For this instance.. I have 2 tables.

1. Journal (Contains the transactions) and

```
| id | date       | debit | credit| amount    |
|----|------------|-------|-------|-----------|
| 1  | 2021-09-01 | 8     | 2     | 5000.000  |
| 6  | 2021-09-22 | 22    | 17    | 4750.000  |
| 8  | 2021-09-05 | 8     | 3     | 1485.000  |
| 9  | 2021-08-10 | 8     | 6     | 108.000   |
| 10 | 2021-07-07 | 8     | 23    | 98756.000 |
```

2. Ledgers Account Names

```
| id | name                              | desc                              | status |
|----|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|--------|
| 1  | Assets                            | Current Assets                    | 1      |
| 2  | Stockholders equity               | Stockholders or Owners equity     | 1      |
| 3  | Liability                         | Liabilities related accounts      | 1      |
| 4  | Operating Revenues                | Operating Revenues                | 1      |
| 5  | Operating Expenses                | Operating Expenses                | 1      |
| 6  | Non-operating revenues and gains  | Non-operating revenues and gains  | 1      |
| 7  | Non-operating expenses and losses | Non-operating expenses and losses | 1      |
| 8  | Cash                              | For cash transaction              | 1      |
```

Now *from my program, if I select an account (populated from ledgers) and submit it will send its id. With that account id I have populate all the transactions against that account id.*

**For Example: if i chose cash account it will send lets say it will send 8 as id.**

now

1. the SQL query has to populate date and amount from journal, and account name from ledger - name of account that is against the id 8 in a  transaction. for example if it is 2 then it shall return "Stockholders equity" as name.
2. The amount should be in **credit** column if the given id 8 in debit or the amount should be in **debit** column if the given id 8 is in credit

and as in above points, from program, if account id is passed as 8 (i.e. "cash")
then
the **DESIRED OUPUT** of a **SQL SELECT** Query result should look like this...

```
| Date       | Account                          |    Debit |    Credit |
|------------|----------------------------------|---------:|----------:|
| 2021-09-01 | Stockholders equity              |     0.00 |   5000.00 |
| 2021-09-05 | Liability                        |     0.00 |   1485.00 |
| 2021-08-10 | Non-operating revenues and gains |     0.00 |    108.00 |
| 2021-07-07 | Land                             |     0.00 |  98756.00 |
| 2021-02-25 | Land                             | 21564.00 |      0.00 |
| 2021-01-19 | Vehicles                         |     0.00 |  23132.00 |
| 2020-05-19 | Buildings Asset                  |   465.00 |      0.00 |
| 2019-09-01 | Non-operating revenues and gains |   315.00 |      0.00 |
| 2019-05-23 | Land                             |   346.00 |      0.00 |
| 2018-04-12 | Cash                             |     0.00 |    697.00 |
| 2017-05-15 | Non-operating revenues and gains |     0.00 |    999.00 |
| 2018-06-18 | Operating Revenues               |     0.00 |    496.00 |
| 2018-06-23 | Liability                        |     0.00 |    426.00 |
| 2019-12-12 | Assets                           |     0.00 |   1684.00 |
| 2018-07-15 | Land                             |     0.00 |   1649.00 |
| 2018-07-22 | Land                             |  3666.00 |      0.00 |
| 2018-05-14 | Non-operating revenues and gains |     0.00 |    489.00 |
| 2018-09-16 | Equipment                        |   692.00 |      0.00 |
| 2021-04-18 | Non-operating revenues and gains |  4986.00 |      0.00 |
| 2020-04-19 | Land                             |  4956.00 |      0.00 |
| 2019-03-15 | Buildings Asset                  |     0.00 |   4988.00 |
| 2019-12-04 | Inventory                        |     0.00 |   7946.00 |
| 2019-08-25 | Stockholders equity              |     0.00 |  19449.00 |
|            |                                  |          |           |
|            | Total                            | 36990.00 | 167304.00 |
|            | Balance                          |          | 130314.00 |
```

here is the sample data in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe2a00/2

Can you please give me an idea on how to populate this result table with SQL query using joins and/or unions or should I use some other way...

**Please help with answer!**

Comment: Please create and post some sample data as textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (5-7 rows) and desired output for this data. The best way - create online fiddle and post a link. Also specify server version (show complete output for `SELECT VERSION();`)

Comment: @Akina Edited my question as instructed. Hope this give you an idea of my problem. A link to SQL fiddle also added. My MariaDB version is 10.4.19-MariaDB

Comment: *Edited my question as instructed.* Where is precise desired output for the data from your fiddle? I cannot find it.

Comment: The specified result should _match_ the given sample data. I don't know what `...` means.

Comment: @Akina [link] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe2a00/2)

Comment: @jarlh the result I posted is a sample which i should actually have (but as of now I cant find a solution/SQL query to populate such structure). `...` means there may be 1or more rows

Comment: Provide **DESIRED OUTPUT** for the data from your fiddle.

Comment: @Akina added the desired output for the data in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `Total`:

```sql
SELECT journal.date `Date`,
       ledger.name Account,
       CASE WHEN journal.dracc = 8 
            THEN 0.000
            ELSE amount
            END Debit,
       CASE WHEN journal.dracc = 8
            THEN amount
            ELSE 0.000
            END Credit
FROM journal
JOIN ledger ON (ledger.id, 8) IN ((dracc, cracc), (cracc, dracc));
```

With `Total`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT GROUPING(journal.id) 
            THEN MAX(journal.date) 
            END `Date`,
       CASE WHEN NOT GROUPING(journal.id) 
            THEN MAX(ledger.name) 
            ELSE 'Total'
            END Account,
       SUM(CASE WHEN journal.dracc = 8 
                THEN 0
                ELSE amount
                END) Debit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN journal.dracc = 8
                THEN amount
                ELSE 0
                END) Credit
FROM journal
JOIN ledger ON (ledger.id, 8) IN ((dracc, cracc), (cracc, dracc))
GROUP BY journal.id WITH ROLLUP;
```

With `Total` and `Balance`:

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT GROUPING(journal.id) 
            THEN MAX(journal.date) 
            END `Date`,
       CASE WHEN NOT GROUPING(journal.id) 
            THEN MAX(ledger.name) 
            ELSE 'Total'
            END Account,
       SUM(CASE WHEN journal.dracc = 8 
                THEN 0
                ELSE amount
                END) Debit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN journal.dracc = 8
                THEN amount
                ELSE 0
                END) Credit
FROM journal
JOIN ledger ON (ledger.id, 8) IN ((dracc, cracc), (cracc, dracc))
GROUP BY journal.id WITH ROLLUP
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'Balance', NULL, Credit - Debit
FROM cte
WHERE `Date` IS NULL;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=794f87b054848b1584a6c8dd2dd5d47c

If your MySQL version is 5.x then:

- replace `WHEN NOT GROUPING(journal.id)` with `WHEN journal.id IS NOT NULL`
- convert CTE to subquery

Comment: My DB engine is **MariaDB 10.4.19** *the first query (Without Total) **returns only zero row**. no result is returned as in your example.* In the 2nd and 3rd the **GROUPING* function is not available in mariaDB. For which I found your answer on other thread to use ROLLUP. Please give an idea why in maria db there is no result for first Example!

Comment: Found the error! a line of code `GROUP BY journal.id WITH ROLLUP;` is missing at the end of the first query Thanks for your immediate solution!

Comment: @CodeJunior *My DB engine is MariaDB 10.4.19* Such info must be the most first in any question. *In the 2nd and 3rd the *GROUPING function is not available in mariaDB.* ?? The solution can be found in the answer - why you have not applied it? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3fc61a1749177510ea5c07510d13571f

Comment: added the DB engine info to the question. And I have applied the solution from your answer and works now. and have already marked your answer as accepted.